# Should tabs on the Recent Activity page be rolling windows?

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

The tabs on the Recent Activity page show Today, Yesterday, This Week, This Month, etc.

The time windows that implement these tabs are simple blocks that go off the calendar Day/Week/Month.  Since today is the 2nd of this month, when I click on the "This Month" tab, I get the activity from the last two days.  This isn't what I expected to see.

I would expect this be rolling windows, based off the last 24 hours, 168 hours, etc.

Month is a little hairy, since months have variable length.  This could be fudged by simply being 31 days).  Also, users might be confused if Yesterday, Last Week, and Last Month used rolling windows.

Would it be less surprising, or more useful, to change the today/this week/this month tabs to be rolling windows?

This could be implemented by changing the existing tabs, adding rolling window tabs, or adding a user option to change the tabs to be rolling windows.

Comment: An excellent idea. What good is showing the current month if, at the beginning of the month, it only shows a handful of days' worth of stuff. Ditto for the Week tab. Week and Month should be for the 7 or 30 (31?) days up to and including today. Last Week/Month should be for the 1 week/month period prior to that.

Answer (score 2):

My vote goes for, Pick One and Stick With It.

Then, document the crap out of it, so people know what the heck it is doing.

Really, either way is fine, and they both make sense.  I just think it needs to be better documented.

Comment: 'jjnguy' Nelson: But I want rolling windows, and what I want is right for every user, everywhere ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've just noticed the same thing on the ["Users" page](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=month) for sites - this feature feels a bit pointless at the moment, as "Month", "Quarter" and "Year" all show the same results as they are all covering the period "2012-01-01 - Today".

[image: Month, Quarter and Year all the same]