# Users list: User reputation according to quarter and year does not work but give month scores

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

All these links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=quarter
- https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=year

gives this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=month

Same situation on meta users reputation listing.

I mean:

Each tab: month , quarter, year comes selected and tabs working but not content

I tested on ff 9.0.1 & i.e 8 compatibility.

Comment: They work for me, i.e. they filter by quarter and year, in Firefox 9.0.1. What browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry, that is right. I get the same result as you. Maybe you should clarify your question with an edit that this is what you mean?

Comment: Do you mean that the numbers are identical? It's January, so the reputation earned in this month is identical to this quarter's and this year's.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments: Since it's currently January, the current *month*, *quarter*, and *year* all started on January 1st, so the values being identical is correct.

Comment: I guess the assumption that the OP made (and [myself and others too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59402/33051) on pages with similar functions) was that these were rolling windows - otherwise the "Year" tab is pointless for the first three months of the year as it's the same as the Quarter tab.

Comment: @Zhaph Strange; I see what you mean, but to me, if the Day, Week, Month, and Quarter are not equal on January 1, I instantly think something's wrong with the calculations.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the ranges aren't "Rolling Windows" in time, they are static, which means that:

1. For the first week of the year, the first four pages are the same.
2. For the first month of the year, three pages are the same.
3. For the first three months of the year, quarter and year are identical.

In April, July and October we'll then have:

- The Month and Quarter will show the same data.

And also for any month where the first 1st happens to fall on a Sunday the week and the month will be the same for the first week?

I know dates are annoying, especially Months with their annoying variable lengths, but this feels to me like the least intuitive option with all it's redundancy.

[image: Month, Quarter and Year all the same]

Comment: There is a title that appears on hover if you wait long enough, i.e. "2012-02-01 to today" but you have to think to hover over them for half a second to see it, rather than just click... My screen capture tool hides the mouse stuff :(